# Logical formula in docplex

Tags: cplex, docplex

Given the following formula

[image]

with the table below encode the relationship of `x_0`, `x_1` and `r` for Objective 2':

[image]

For objective 2, we can code it as following with Docplex, where we have either 0 or 1 for priority `p`.

```
CPriorityInFreight = mdl.binary_var_matrix(catPriorities, freights, name='CPriorityInFreight')
FreightMixture = mdl.binary_var_dict(freights, name='FreightMixture')
for p in catPriorities:
    for f in freights:
        # CPriorityInFreight[c, f] = 1 <-> priority c is in freight f
        CPriorityInFreight[p, f] = (
                    1 <= mdl.sum(Assignment[o, f] for o in orders if get_order(o).CategoryPriority == p))

for f in freights:
    # sums == 2 <-> we have both cat 0 and cat 1
    FreightMixture[f] = (2 == mdl.sum(CPriorityInFreight[c, f] for c in catPriorities))


o2 = mdl.sum(FreightMixture[f] for f in freights)
```

In Objective 2', we now have the following code for decision variable declaration (with `FreightMixture` containing value `0,1,2`) and first formula

```
CPriorityInFreight = mdl.binary_var_matrix(catPriorities, freights, name='CPriorityInFreight')
FreightMixture = mdl.integer_var_dict(freights, name='FreightMixture')
for p in catPriorities:
    for f in freights:
        # CPriorityInFreight[c, f] = 1 <-> priority c is in freight f
        CPriorityInFreight[p, f] = (
                    1 <= mdl.sum(Assignment[o, f] for o in orders if get_order(o).CategoryPriority == p))
```

But how do we translate these relationship on second formula of Objective 2' into Docplex? (I am ok with OPL as I can understand it too)

(Of course if there are simpler way to achieve semantically equivalent formulas with Objective 2', feel free to suggest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both in docplex and OPL you can use logical constraints.

In OPL for instance:

```
int R[0..1][0..1]=[[0,0],[2,1]];

dvar boolean x;
dvar boolean y;

dvar int obj;

maximize obj;
subject to
{
  forall(i in 0..1,j in 0..1) (x==i) && (y==j) => (obj==R[i][j]);
}
```

that is generic to any R table and gives

```
obj = 2;
x = 1;
y = 0;
```

You can write less logical constraints if you adapt to the table. In your example

```
int R[0..1][0..1]=[[0,0],[2,1]];

dvar boolean x;
dvar boolean y;

dvar int obj;

maximize obj;
subject to
{
  
  
  (x==0) => (obj==0);
  (x==1) => (obj==2-y);
  
}
```

works fine

And the equivalent code in python docplex

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='logical')

x = mdl.binary_var(name='x')
y = mdl.binary_var(name='y')
obj= mdl.integer_var(name='obj')

R=[[0,0],[2,1]]


decisionVars=[x,y,obj]

for i in range(0,2):
    for j in range(0,2):
        mdl.add_constraint(mdl.if_then((x==i)+(y==j)==2,(obj==R[i][j])))
            

mdl.maximize(obj)

mdl.solve()

for v in decisionVars:
    print(v.name," = ",int(v.solution_value))
```

that gives

```
x  =  1
y  =  0
obj  =  2
```

Comment: Hi Alex, can you help to verify my answer in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72961229/1497720) in DocPlex is that correct?

Comment: I updated my answer with the docplex model I would write to do the same as in OPL. Many more docplex examples in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/

Comment: Hi Alex, this is awesome, I have a new question on Docplex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72979459/binary-var-dict-vs-python-list

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from Alex, this is the corresponding code:

```
CPriorityInFreight = mdl.binary_var_matrix(catPriorities, freights, name='CPriorityInFreight')
FreightRank = mdl.integer_var_dict(freights, name='FreightRank')
for p in catPriorities:
    for f in freights:
        # CPriorityInFreight[p, f] = 1 <-> priority p is in freight f
        CPriorityInFreight[p, f] = (
                    1 <= mdl.sum(Assignment[o, f] for o in orders if get_order(o).CategoryPriority == p))

for f in freights:
    # sums == 2 <-> we have both cat 0 and cat 1
    # FreightRank[f] = (2 == mdl.sum(CPriorityInFreight[p, f] for p in catPriorities))
    mdl.add_constraint(((CPriorityInFreight[0, f]==0) & (CPriorityInFreight[1, f]==1)) <= (FreightRank[f]==0))
    mdl.add_constraint(((CPriorityInFreight[0, f] == 1) & (CPriorityInFreight[1, f] == 0)) <= (FreightRank[f] == 2))
    mdl.add_constraint(((CPriorityInFreight[0, f] == 0) & (CPriorityInFreight[1, f] == 0)) <= (FreightRank[f] == 0))
    mdl.add_constraint(((CPriorityInFreight[0, f] == 1) & (CPriorityInFreight[1, f] == 1)) <= (FreightRank[f] == 1))

FreightRankSum = mdl.sum(FreightRank[f] for f in freights)
```